# WP7: Whats the equivalent of paint or onDraw or drawRect method?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How can i do custom drawing in WP7. Whats the equivalent of paint or onDraw or drawRect method in WP7? .Net framework has onRender method which is not available in silverlight for Windows Phone. Please suggest.

I am looking at some thing like

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
{
      SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush  = new SolidColorBrush();
      mySolidColorBrush.Color = Colors.LimeGreen;
      Pen myPen = new Pen(Brushes.Blue, 10);
      Rect myRect = new Rect(0, 0, 500, 500);
      dc.DrawRectangle(mySolidColorBrush, myPen, myRect);
}
```

The above mentioned stuff is available in .NET framework, but not in silverlight for Windows Phone. I have seen the Canvas, Shape, classes. The problem is I have to do a lot of drawing which i guess if i create objects of these classes directly will be heavy. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the inkpresenter

http://www.nickharris.net/2010/03/silverlight-for-mobile-on-windows-phone-7-inkpresenter-fun/